# Floating Point Arithmetic, C/C++ the way to go?

Tags: php, c++, web-applications

I'm creating a web application that does some very heavy floating point arithmetic calculations, and lots of them! I've been reading a lot and have read you can make C(and C++) functions and call them from within PHP, I was wondering if I'd notice a speed increase by doing so?

I would like to do it this way even if it's only a second difference, unless it's actually slower.

Comment: I would recommend you focus on making your application work and worry about optimizing it later if you encounter problems.

Comment: I agree with the above comment.  I DO think it would be faster (especially if it really is as heavy in calculations as you say it is).  Its really difficult to say how much faster it would be with only this information.

Comment: thanks for the advice! That is my plan for now, was interested in the learning experience of making the two work together if there was a performance gain possible.

Comment: Functions that do what exactly? If you're just planning on doing arithmetic calculations (e.g.: 10 / 2, etc.), outsourcing this to a PHP extension will probably take more time than just doing it in PHP.

Comment: I'll be passing about 6 numbers, and it will do around 75-100 calculations and pass the answers back. There won't be small function calls here and there it will be one big call. That was something I was interested in seeing if it would take more time to call C then just doing it PHP.

Comment: If you don't tell us anything about the algorithm this is just going to be nonspecific and chatty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It all depends on the actual number of calculations you are doing. If you have thousands of calculations to do then certainly it will be worthwhile to write an extension to handle it for you. In particular, if you have a lot of data this is where PHP really fails: it's memory manager can't handle a lot of objects, or large arrays (based on experience working with such data).

If the algorithm isn't too difficult you may wish to write it in PHP first anyway. This gives you a good reference speed but more importantly it'll help define exactly what API you need to implement in a module.

---

Update to "75-100 calculations with 6 numbers".

If you are doing this only once per page load I'd suspect it won't be a significant part of the overall load time (depends what else you do of course). If you are calling this function many times then yes, even 75 ops might be slow -- however since you use only 6 variables perhaps their optimizer will do a good job (whereas with 100 variables it's pretty much guaranteed not to).

Comment: When you want to verify that you had any speed increase from a C/C++ module you would need a reference implementation to measure against anyway.

Comment: @TomKerr, never forget that PHP is really slow with computation/data. Even 50+ float operations will be a *lot* faster in C. The question is, is the time relevant to the page load time at all. At a few thousands operations on floats you're probably hitting that point.  PHP is also quite type unsafe, so it might actually be far easier to write a complex algorithm in C.

Comment: @edA-qamort-ora-y: On what basis can you claiming that C calculations will be so much faster than PHP's? PHP is very close to C's level, especially for things like math. Doing 100,000 FP simple calculations in PHP would take about 25ms. Going into the trouble of building a PHP extension, *with the so well documented Zend Engine*, to get faster times than that is probably a waste of time.

Comment: @netcoder, based on experience doing data processing in PHP. Data access is the biggest problem: loading/storing large amount of data in arrays. If that is not an issue, say with 6 variables, you may do alright. However, due to dynamic typing and lacking a JIT there is just no way PHP can come anywhere close to machine code compiled language (like C) in terms of calculation performance.

Answer (score 0):

Check [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/).

Swig is a way to make php (and other languages) modules from your C sources rather easily.

Comment: Thanks for the link but my question was about the whether I'll receive a legitimate speed increase.

Comment: You will not know until you try.

Comment: does swig actually run at the speed C would? By the looks of things it just converts existing code into PHP. I'm still working on getting it up and working and have not been able to test.

Comment: Swig is a way to make php (and other languages) modules from your C sources rather easily.

Comment: I've been trying to set this up, but swig keeps giving me errors like this when trying to do the tutorial on the website: example_wrap.c:689:18: zend.h: No such file or directory

Comment: OS? Compiler? Examples on SWIG site work well in Linux with gcc compiler and will require some tricks if you are using Windows.

Comment: Im using ubuntu the latest version. I have no compiler intalled on that machine, that I know of. When I call gcc the terminal doesn't complain about it, but when it tries to compile it doesn't know what zend.h is.

Comment: Assuming you are trying to run `gcc \`php-config --includes\` -fpic -c example_wrap.c`. Does `php-config --includes` produce any output? You probably need to install `php-devel` or `php-dev` package or whatever it is called in ubuntu.

Comment: thanks for the help. Got that line to run smoothly but PHP just stops as soon as it gets to the include file, and doesn't come up with any errors that I can see. I've turned the dl() file on in the php.ini file as well.

Comment: Before even starting with php you need to create implementations of functions defined in `example.i`, compile and link that implementation with generated wrapper into extension file. Then you need to copy (or create a link) to your extension to the place where php extensions are stored (as php most probably will not allow you to load extension from arbitrary location for security considerations), on my machine it is `/usr/lib/php/extensions`. And only after that you can try to include that example php and call it's functions.